# Putting XForm nodes in Regular Expression

Tags: regex, validation, xpath, xforms

I am trying to compare 2 XForm nodes using regular expression. For example,

- Node 1 is /data/Q1
- Node 2 is /data/Q2

What I want to do is put a constraint in Node 2 saying value of Node 2 cannot be greater than the value in Node 1. I put the following statement in the bind element:

```
constraint=regex(/data/Q1 >= /data/Q2)
```

But this is not working.

Is there anyway I can make the regex read a value from previous nodes?

Comment: Can you give examples of the data value in Q1 and Q2 and explain why you need a regular expression to compare them? With typed data in XForms I would expect that simply comparing values should be possible and suffice e.g. `/data/Q1 >= /data/Q2`.

Comment: Provide a detailed explanation about "not working". This will help understand the issue clearly

Answer (score 0):

There is no function named `regex()` defined in xpath or xforms. So if this isn't an implementation-specific feature (if so - please add the xforms engine you're using to your question), the constraint won't work even with valid regular expressions. If you want to check if a node's value matches a regex, you should use the [`matches()`](http://www.w3.org/TR/xpath-functions/#func-matches) function that's part of XPath.

With the `matches()` function, it should be possible to use XPath for the function's arguments. Assuming that the node `/data/pattern` contains a valid regex pattern as string, and `/data/value` has the value to check if it matches that pattern, `matches(/data/value, /data/pattern)` should work. You could even put this into the `constraint` attribute of a `xforms:bind`: `constraint="matches(/data/value, /data/pattern)"`.

Generally, as Martin commented, you don't need the `matches()` function for a simple value comparison of two nodes. Just use the usual [comparison expressions](http://www.w3.org/TR/xpath20/#id-comparisons) that are available in XPath.